# Piping using toolbox in Google Container Optimized OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-os

I'm trying to create a script that runs on [google container optimized os](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/) that calls curl using [toolbox](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox) but I want to pipe the results to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) by doing something like this:

```
sudo toolbox curl ... | sudo toolbox jq -r ".something"
```

but if I do this I get this error message:

```
Directory tree /var/lib/toolbox/root-gcr.io_google-containers_toolbox-20161110-02 is currently busy.
```

If I remove `toolbox` from the pipe (and just pipe to a command like grep that exists in the container) then everything works. But how can I pipe from curl to jq using toolbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by doing:

```
sudo toolbox bash -c 'curl ... | jq -r ".something"'
```

Comment: Not fully applicable to this case (as you fixed the pipes) but if toolbox session is not stopped correctly, it could be killed with this combo `ps -ef | grep [t]oolbox | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9`